# How close html page with link or button , etc?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, xhtml

Hy guys,
i made a upload page, after the sucess of operation i would like to close the html page automatically or by a link or something.

window.close don't work in this case, 'cause is not a window pop up.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: can you show us the page or code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>There is no way to do this and that's a good thing. It may confuse the user. Instead, show a message telling the user that they may close the window now.</del>

I see you want to close the greybox from within the child page. Try

```
top.GB_hide();
```

Comment: @Delan, is not a page actually, i'm using a plugin 'greybox' that show a beatiful pop up, but is not a pop up actually, 'cause i try windows.close() already and nothing.

Comment: Ah. I'll investigate how to close `greybox` popups and update my answer. Sorry, I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Delan, no problem dude.
Here is the link:http://orangoo.com/labs/greybox/installation.html

Comment: Done, I've added a possible solution, `top.GB_hide()`. If that doesn't work, try `parent.parent.GB_hide()`.

Comment: could you paste the code in pastebin ? (you're fast dude =) )

Answer (score 2):

If `window.close()` won't work, you can't do anything else.

Which is good, because I don't want sites closing *my* window.

You could try `window.close()`, and then immediately after it update the DOM with a message such as "This window may be closed." That way, if you ever can close the window (perhaps some browsers may let you), you will cover both bases.

Answer (score 0):

some kind of hack here...but may not work in all browsers

```
window.opener=null;
window.open('','_self');
window.close();
```

Comment: It's not a real window; it's a 'greybox' frame/div.